# writing matrix columns with different precisions(significant digits) in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, precision, significant-digits

I have a matrix 
m=[10 15.675; 13.5 34.987; 20 55.5];
 I want to write this matrin on o txt file. I want to use different precisions for each columns. For example 1 for 1st column and 2 for 2nd column.

Desired output:

10.0    15.68

13.5    34.99

20.0    55.50

I am currently using 
dlmwrite(fileName, m,'-append','delimiter','\t','precision',2,'roffset'
,1,'newline','pc');

However, this applies 2 significant after '.' for all columns.

Is there any way to apply different significant digits for each column of a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something simple like this?

```
m = [10 15.675; 13.5 34.987; 20 55.5];
file = fopen('file.txt', 'w');

for ii = 1:size(m, 1)
    fprintf(file, '%0.1f %0.2f\n', m(ii, 1), m(ii, 2));
end
```

I've edited to add the '\n'

Comment: It works thank you.

I use this version without for loop:
fprintf(file, '%0.1f %0.2f \n', m');